# trim(remove) the last 8 eight characters from a result column of a oracle sql query, irrespective of the result column size

Tags: sql, oracle

The results of my oracle sql query has a column with part description with color code and size like `CASHMERE POPOVER HOODIE, BL8133, S`. I need to remove the last 11 characters for all the results., irrespective of the result column size

For eg , the results are

```
CASHMERE POPOVER HOODIE, BL8133, S
STRETCH PERFECT SHIRT IN CLAS, WA9148, L
```

My expected results :

```
CASHMERE POPOVER HOODIE
STRETCH PERFECT SHIRT IN CLAS
```

Answer (score 0):

Use functions [LENGTH](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17952_01/refman-5.1-en/string-functions.html#function_length) and [SUBSTR](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17952_01/refman-5.1-en/string-functions.html#function_substring):

```
select CASE WHEN LENGTH("partdesc") > 11 
THEN 
    SUBSTR("partdesc", 1, LENGTH("partdesc")-11) 
ELSE
    "partdesc"
END AS trimmedDesc
from YourTable
```

SQLFiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/4d8fc/12).

P.S. In the title of your question, you said you have to remove the last 8 characters, but then, in the question, you said 11. Anyway, the query is the same, using 8 or 11 as needed.

Answer (score 0):

```
substr(part_desc,1,length(part_desc)-10)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT SUBSTR(str, 1, Instr(str, substr(str, -11))-1 ) final_str FROM
(
 SELECT 'CASHMERE POPOVER HOODIE, BL8133, S' str FROM dual
 UNION
 SELECT 'STRETCH PERFECT SHIRT IN CLAS, WA9148, L' FROM dual
)
/
```